# Identifying Lists of Numbers With Regular Expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with data from an online math tutor program, and I'd like to be able to identify some features of those problems. For example, for the following question:

```
Find the median of the 7 numbers in the following list:
[22, 13, 5, 16, 4, 12, 30]
```

I'd like to know if

```
1. the problem includes a list, 
2. how long the longest list in the problem is, and 
3. how many numbers are in the problem total.
```

So for the problem above, it has a list, the list is 7 numbers long, and there are 8 numbers in the problem total.

I've written the following regex script that can identify positive and negative numbers and floats, but I can't figure out how to identify a series of numbers that are in a list:

```
'[-+]{0,1}[0-9]+\.{0,1}(?! )[0-9]+'
```

Additionally, the data is poorly formatted, all of the following examples are possible for what a list of numbers can look like:

```
[1, 2, 3]
1, 2, 3
1,2,3.
1,    2,    3,    4,    5
```

I've been working on this for a few days now, and have stopped being able to make any progress on it. Can anyone help? It might not even be a problem to solve with a regex, I'm just not sure how to go about it from this point.

Comment: Can `"\b[+-]?((\d+)|(\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d+))"g` help? ;).

Comment: what do you want to extract? If it is just the digits the regex pretty basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the answer provided by alfasin, you can do a second search to find sub-strings encased in a list:

```
s = '''1, 2, 3
       [4, 5, 6]
       3, 2, 1. '''

l = re.findall(r'\[.*\]', s)
# number of lists in string
print len(l)

# largest array by length of numbers in each list found
print max([re.findall(r'\d+', i) for i in l])

# number of numbers total in problem
print re.findall(r'\d+', s)
```

Comment: This is good, but the problems aren't always so cleanly formatted. Having brackets to denote a list is not guaranteed - they can exist in the middle of a string.

Comment: Can you provide more edge cases? If the only commonality between lists is that it is a group of numbers (two or more) separated by a comma and whitespace with no intervening characters, you could create a regex to pull out the numbers that way. Maybe `'\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+\s*)+'`

Comment: This looks like it works great as a baseline. I can add back in the ability to catch decimals and negatives. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get the input as a string - you can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to extract only the numbers out of it:

```
import re

s = """[1, -2, 3]
        1, 2, 3
        1,2,3.
        1,    2,    3,    4,    5"""

res = re.findall(r'-?\d+', s)
print res # ['1', '-2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

# and if you want to turn the strings into numbers:
print map(int, res)  # [1, -2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You need to catch negative numbers too

Comment: Thanks - I have gotten this far. What I need now is to know which sets of numbers form a list. So for your example, I would need something that looks like the following:

    [[1, -2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1,2,3.], [1,    2,    3,    4,    5]]

Comment: @StefanS. if you consider each line as a separate list, break the string into lines `s.split("\n")` and only then use `re.findall` on each line.